# Create border-bottom smaller than element and with thicker middle

Tags: css

I'm using some stylized HRs to create section separators.

But now I'm trying to create a H1 element with a border bottom smaller than H1 width (variable width according to the width of the H1 text) and with a thicker middle (height).

Something like this:

[image: This is the idea]

I scoured several search sources trying to find a solution but found nothing like it.

I tried to use :after and :before but still stuck.
Any idea?

What I've tried so far:

```css
h1 {
  display:inline;
  border-bottom:1px solid black;
}

h1:after {
 content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom:3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<h1>
My Text
</h1>
```

Comment: you got any code you tried?

Comment: Sure. I'll post a Fiddle in a second.

Comment: Here is what I get.. https://jsfiddle.net/ogy6yqgt/

Comment: I get two borders.. But I cant manipulate their widths

Comment: Please post your jsfiddle in the question itself. Posting links without any code snippets is not allowed in SO.

Comment: Sorry about that, Andrew!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily do such thing with linear-gradient with no need of extra markup or pseudo element:

```css
h1 {
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:3em;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(red 0 0) 50% calc(100% - 2px)/80% 2px,
   linear-gradient(red 0 0) 50% 100%            /40% 6px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
```

Comment: That's awesome!

Comment: I was using borders instead of background!

Comment: @RusselRiehle it can be done with border also, but this one is easier and no need to rely on extra element and pseudo element ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements to create the lines:

```css
h1 {
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:3em;
  position: relative;
  font-family: Impact, Arial;
  color: #444;
  font-weight: 900;
}
h1::before,
h1::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: #ea596e;
  position: absolute;
}
h1::before {
  width: 40%;
  height: 5px;
  bottom: -12px;
  left: 30%;
}
h1::after {
  width: 80%;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<h1>my &lt;h1&gt; tag</h1>
```